# SelectedItem binding stops working when using custom DataTemplate on Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, caliburn.micro

I've got a simple `ListBox` which entries are bound from an `ObservableCollection<T>` inside the view model. Additionally, I got a binding to a *SelectedItem* property.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry}" />
```

For some requirements I need to modify the actual list box items, so I made a custom `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListBoxItem ... />
</DataTemplate>
```

However, as soon as the `DataTemplate` is there, the *SelectedItem* binding stops working. It just doesn't fire at all, no matter what I do. If I take the whole `DataTemplate` away, it starts working again. Since I've got a custom `ListBoxItem`, do I have to somehow bind itself to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox`? Or am I simply missing something here?

---

#### Full Code

```
<ListBox x:Name="Entries" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5, 5, 0, 5" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem Background="{Binding EntryColor}" 
                             ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" 
                             ToolTip="{Binding SequenceNumber, StringFormat=Sequence {0:D12}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: You don't need `ItemTemplate`. Just put these properties into the style.

Answer (score 1):

In your template, replace `ListViewItem` with something else, such as a `TextBlock`. This works for me (being otherwise similar to your code):

Item:

```
public class Item
{
    public Brush EntryColor { get; set; }

    public long SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public string Text => $"Item {SequenceNumber}";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

List:

```
public class List
{
    public IList<Item> Entries => new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { EntryColor = Brushes.Cyan, SequenceNumber = 1 },
            new Item { EntryColor = Brushes.Red, SequenceNumber = 2 },
            new Item { EntryColor = Brushes.Orange, SequenceNumber = 3 },
        };

    public Item SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <local:List />
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <ListBox x:Name="Entries" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5, 5, 0, 5" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    Background="{Binding EntryColor}"
                    FontSize="20"
                    Text="{Binding Text}"
                    ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0"
                    ToolTip="{Binding SequenceNumber, StringFormat=Sequence {0:D12}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I suspect the `SelectedItem` binding may have a problem connecting an `Item` with a `ListBoxItem`, but I'm not entirely sure what's happening here. At any rate, there's no need for `ListViewItem`s in the template -- the `ListView` creates those automatically a needed.

**ADDENDUM**

When the template contains a `TextBlock`, the visual tree looks like this:

[image: Visual tree with TextBlock]

The `DataContext` of all these are `Item`, which is what we want.

When the template contains a `ListViewItem`, however, we get *two* of them:

[image: Visual tree with ListBoxItem]

The `DataContext` of the inner `ContentPresenter` and `TextBlock` is just the string value, which makes the binding fail.

Then I thought to change the `Content` binding:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListViewItem
        Background="{Binding EntryColor}"
        FontSize="20"
        Content="{Binding}"
        ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0"
        ToolTip="{Binding SequenceNumber, StringFormat=Sequence {0:D12}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

That fixes the `DataContext` of the inner `ContentPresenter`, but not its `TextBlock`. Final try:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListViewItem
        Background="{Binding EntryColor}"
        FontSize="20"
        ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0"
        ToolTip="{Binding SequenceNumber}">
        <ListViewItem.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </ListViewItem.Content>
    </ListViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

...which *does* give the `TextBlock` the appropriate `DataContext`.

The `SelectedItem` binding still doesn't work, though, so I'm not all that much wiser after this bit of spelunking...